# Is there a way to make transparent canvas for custom paint in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, canvas, transparent

Does anyone know how to make a transparent canvas in custom paint in Flutter?  I have some drawings on one canvas and others on a different canvas. I want to merge these two canvases (2 layers) as one. However, since the canvas is not transparent, this seems to be impossible in Flutter. I wonder if this can be done by using paint BlendMode?

Comment: `Canvas` is transparent:, if you dont draw anything in some ares they will be transparent

Comment: thanks pskink. It's good to know. I read through the doc but didn't see anywhere it mentioned that canvas is transparent.